# Google Universal Analytics - Track download details

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am using the new Google Universal Analytics code and it tracks my page-views perfectly.

In addition to that I would like to track downloaded document details such as document name, UserID, etc.

When I googled, the suggestion was to include tracking code in OnClick method. But in my MVC application I am using ajax call and I am not using OnClick.

Is there any other option to track the same. Please let me know if there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Onclick is an implementation detail - the principle is that the tracking call should be placed in some sort of callback for the user action.

If you do an ajax call then you would presumably place the tracking call in the ajax success event (and check the response to see if the user action did return the expected result from the server). It's hard to be more specific without seeing some code.